# Tried all possible solutions for auto import in vscode in next.js (also problem in finding the module even after giving relative path)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, frontend, importerror

In next.js , in src folder , I've created two folder app and components, in app folder there are two files page.tsx and layout.tsx . the page.tsx in the main page where the display is done in localhost . In components folder there are two files name header.tsx and logo.tsx.The path is shown in the SS [path_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cLlp.png).

When i try to import the header.tsx in page.tsx .like this [page.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0lNZ.png)
I get problem as [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT22y.png). the header.tsx is this [header.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvn4M.png).

The main concern was obiviously not able to find the module .but all I think if there was auto import Then it would have been easier .

I've tried almost everything possible things I found , I tried creating jsconfig.json and tried to exclude node_modules but didn't worked , I also tried to change settings in user setting and it didn't worked . All these are for auto import . even after giving the relative path it says has no default export .I also tried restarting the vscode and didn't work . I feel like the problem in within the code as well . by changing anything in the json it hasnt worked .

I've the latest version of next.js

Comment: 1. for typescript you need a [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) not jsconfig.json, probably best to use a TS template using [create-next-app](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/create-next-app), setting this up manually is no fun, VSCode autoimports should be ok then 2. "no default export" means  no export like `export default somefunctionOrConstant;`, what does your `logo.tsx` export? If it's named like `export function LogoComponent() {...}` you need to import it with name: `import { LogoComponent } from '../components/logo'` .

Comment: @makadev sir thankyou for the reply , tsconfig.json also doesn't works , and my logo.tsx has 
import React from 'react'

export const Logo = () => {
  return (
    <div>logo</div>
  )
}

and i exported with export default only  and even if i try  import { HeaderComponent} from "../components/logo' it says module has no exported member 'Header'

i didn't get when you said setting this up mannnually is no fun, when i started the project i used npx create-next-app my-app